# Bash Shell Script Loop not processing more than one command

Tags: bash, shell

Here's my loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=3

for i in $(seq $count)
do
   echo $i
   killall midori
   midori http://www.test.com/test.html?id=$i &
done
```

But it won't kill midori and launch another one in the background to continue the loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It most likely works exactly as you want it to, except you're killing midori within a millisecond of starting it, before it gets a chance to open a window or anything.

Try adding a `sleep` to give it a chance to start up and do something before you kill it:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=3

for i in $(seq $count)
do
   echo $i
   killall midori
   midori http://www.test.com/test.html?id=$i &
   sleep 10
done
```